# Why my url modifier doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, meteor

I want to modify the url when I click on a button to remove the www.something/**thispart** so I made this code:

```
//JS from alerte.html
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';

import './404.html';



Template.error.onRendered(function alerteOnCreated() {
});

Template.error.events({
  'click #goHome404': function(){
    var url = window.location.href.split("/")[2]
    window.location.href = url ;
    document.location.href= url;
    window.location.replace(url);
  }
});


Template.error.helpers({
});
```

Nothing happens despite in the terminal console there is the right thing when I click on the `goHome404`:

Comment: none of the 3 methods are working here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I make it works by using `Router.go("/")`

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use this
`window.location.pathname`
This return to u only request pathname

Comment: But it doesn't answer to my question, the code doesn't modify the url despite I can get what I want to get